# Implementing Single sign on in asp.net and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on

Currently I have a code modules which contains code necessary to authenticate user credentials and it includes AD users validation also. now I have a requirement to auto logging in without prompting the user to enter username and password if the user browses the application from company's network domain.

Can it be done via Single Sign on?if so how to implement it?

Comment: is your app accessible from both internet and intranet? you may want to take a look at this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic

Comment: Intranet only but not limited to AD user only. administrator can add users via admin module.

Comment: how do the users added via 'admin module' access to the app? in another word, are they not part of domain users?

Comment: Yes. We have another admin system(Windows app) to manage users via which we add users, they can be either AD user or normal users. user can be validated in the following order.
1. Single sign on 2. AD users 3. Normal users

Comment: if an normal user browse to your app and you have Integrated Authenticated turned on for the app, will `Page.User.Identity` be null?

Comment: Currently, I use session variables to get user details after user successfully logged in.

Comment: are all of your current and future users running windows and joined the domain? if yes, then you can use BigOrangeSU's suggestion (integrated windows authentication). otherwise, you'll need to implement your own SSO with database.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way would be to use Integrated Windows Auth and ensure your computers are connected to the domain, and then the computers are set to have your host in the "Intranet" zone in IE, therefore your credentials would be passed. If this isn't an option perhaps take a look at ADFS or OAuth where you can implement SSO across many sites using Cookies, Tokens, Claims, headers, etc.

Thanks!

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Our system is already running with custom login implementation, Would it be having impact if we are going to change it to Windows Auth?

Comment: You would get the SSO experience. What system are running? Perhaps you can integrate that system into your application?

Comment: Sorry for my lacking skills in SSO, I am running in windows XP.

Comment: One note of caution with Integrated Auth: it works fine enough in an all IE environment, but is a terrible pain in the ass if you have to support any other browsers.

Comment: most enterprise will probably support up to 2 browsers only. enabling integrated windows authentication (ntlm) is easy in firefox. http://sivel.net/2007/05/firefox-ntlm-sso/

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can implement sso via cookie, if you have cross domain request in iframe in IE browser, please remember to add P3P in http response header when set cookie